# Apply navigation drawer show/hide mecanism to sidebar layout

Tags: java, android

I have a layout at the **right** side of the screen that I would like to hide and show by dragging in a navigation drawer fashion but I don't want it to be a navigation layout, just the usual layout. Can this be done? How exactly?

Comment: I do not understand your main problem. Imm are talking about that scenario ; when user drags the navigation drawer, that drawer can fill all screen? If problem is that what is the "exactly point" for using navigation drawer? Go and create a fragment or an activity. Otherwise I apologize for my wrong thinking.

Comment: if you mean that you don't want to use just list view for navigation layout but something different - sure, just wrap it in groupview (layout have to have single child) and you have any layout you want. Note that navigation layout can be parametrised as what is the side the drawer should slide from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. One way would be to implement gestures. (http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) Probably overriding and using onScroll would work best. Basically when that method is called you can then either animate the navigation view into the current view port, or adjust the view location as you drag left/right.